# Como usar corretamente Ngrok com Angular-cli?

Tags: angularjs, http, angular, localhost, webhook

### Existe alguma forma correta de usar o Ngrok com Angular?

Estou tentando fazer um tunelamento para minha aplicação que roda em localhost, criando um web (URL) aleatório para disponibilizar na internet, com isso consigo efetuar os testes de Webhook da API Moip Assinatura.

Acontece que quando inserido a URL aleatória criada na barra de endereço do navegador Google Chrome e executado, carrega o título da minha aplicação mas não renderiza o conteúdo da minha aplicação na página.

O Browser fica tentando carregar, é como se estivesse em um loop infinito, olhei no console para verificar se houve algum erro, não há nenhum erro retornado e através do endereço: localhost:4200 executa normalmente.

**Prompt de Comando:**

```
ng serve

ngrok http 4200 -host-header="localhost:4200"
```

Comment: na barra network do develper-tools é possível ver se os arquivos estão sendo carregados e o endereço que está sendo chamado, a propósito para que serve o parâmetro -host-header pois nunca usei sempre da certo comigo usando somente ngrok http 4200

Comment: @FelipeDuarte na barra network está carregando os scripts de forma muito lenta e não consegue renderizar a página, estou tentando até em um projeto novo do Angular que não há quase nada pra carregar, mas demora muito e não carrega... o parâmetro host-header é devido ao erro que ocorre: Invalid Host Header.

Comment: Já tentou mudar de porta? para mim sempre deu certo a 80, 8000, 3412... pode ser tanto um simples problema interno na aplicação, como problemas relacionados a sua máquina, como suas configurações de firewall, permissões etc... isso tudo tem na documentação https://ngrok.com/docs caso ache que o erro é no próprio programa, poderá simplesmente abrir um issue no git deles https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok

Comment: estive olhando antes a documentação deles, mas não consegui encontrar nada que pudesse me ajudar... através do que você me disse vi que está carregando os arquivos muito devagar, é como se fosse uma conexão discada... preciso para efetuar testes com webhook mas até agora nada...